# resx files not being deployed

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, resx

I have a asp.net mvc4 web application. I have localized my application fully with the .resx files, with the files contained within a separate project to my main web application.

When I deploy my application, the resx files are not getting deployed. I would like these to be deployed so that I can make resource text changes in the deployed environment.

Any tips how to set this up?

Comment: You should provide more detail, how are you deploying? you mention the resx files are not contained in the main web application, how are you referencing them?

Comment: They are located in another project within the solution and the web application is deployed with normal mvc web publishing.

Answer (score 3):

You just choose that dll that contains the resource files and then go to properties > then choose the following option.

> Copy to Output Directory: Copy always.

Post your update after you try this one
And in the mean time, you can choose the `.resx` files and then select the 
build option as Embedded Resource
 and then rebuild that project. In this case the dll will contain within itself the resource files.

Comment: thanks for the info - where does the .resx file reside after this so I can change it in the deployed environment?

Comment: If you embed it in the dll, it will not be available outside the dll. If not, you can change the resx files. All you have to do is choose the resx files / dll and then choose "Copy to Output Directory as Copy Always".